# XSL inserting attribute with increment from count into nested elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I am transforming a document with the objective of inserting the attribute `@fn` on certain elements with an incremented count value. The count is incrementing correctly, however the attribute is not being inserted on nest elements.

In the below example I've left in a number of elements to see the eventual (possible) complexity of nesting. The Fiddle is [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qtiBou).

The problem is that the first `<seg>` should have the attribute `@fn="1"` and the first `<date>`should have the attribute `@fn="2"` and `<note>` should have `@fn="3"`. Only the `<seg>` is receiving the attribute, evidently the action of copying is not working on nested elements but I don't know how to resolve this.

The original XML is:

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <text>
        <body>
            <ab xml:id="MS609-0017-LA" xml:lang="la">
                <seg n="1" type="dep_event" subtype="event" xml:id="MS609-0017-1" corresp="#MS609-0017-1"><lb break="y" n="35"/>Item. 
                    <date type="deposition_date" sameAs="#MS609-0013">Anno et die quo supra.</date>
                    Poncius de Rozengue testis juratus<note type="public">test note</note> dixit quod vidit <persName ref="#guilhem_vidal_h_lbc-au" role="her">Willelmum 
                        Vital</persName> et socium suum, hereticos, <placeName type="event_loc" ref="#vineyard_of_joan_carabula">juxta 
                            vineam den <persName ref="#joan_carabula_msp-au" role="ref">Johanni<pb n="3v"/><lb break="y" n="1"/>Carabula</persName></placeName>. 
                    Et vidit ibi <persName ref="#guilhem_de_rosengue_msp-au" role="par">Willelmum de Rezenge</persName> 
                    fratrem ipsius testis. <date type="event_date" when="1239">Et sunt<lb break="y" n="4"/>VI anni vel circa.</date></seg>
                <seg n="2" type="dep_event" subtype="belief" xml:id="MS609-0017-2" corresp="#MS609-0017-2">Quisque dapibus nisl sed porta malesuada. 
                    Proin et velit vitae urna elementum accumsan. Nam accumsan vehicula dolor, at lobortis augue. 
                    Cras mollis scelerisque convallis.</seg>
            </ab>
        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

The XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- set numbers to footnotes -->
    <xsl:template match="tei:note[@type='public'] | tei:date[@type=('deposition_date', 'sentence_date', 'oath_date')] | tei:ab/tei:seg[@corresp ne '']">
        <xsl:variable name="fn">
          <xsl:number count="tei:note[@type='public'] | tei:date[@type=('deposition_date', 'sentence_date', 'oath_date')] | tei:ab/tei:seg[@corresp ne '']" format="1" level="any"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="{ name(.) }" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
            <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="fn">
              <xsl:value-of select="$fn"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <text>
        <body>
            <ab xml:id="MS609-0017-LA" xml:lang="la">
                <seg n="1" type="dep_event" subtype="event" xml:id="MS609-0017-1" corresp="#MS609-0017-1" fn="1"><lb break="y" n="35"/>Item. 
                    <date type="deposition_date" sameAs="#MS609-0013" fn="2">Anno et die quo supra.</date>
                    Poncius de Rozengue testis juratus<note type="public" fn="3">test note</note> dixit quod vidit <persName ref="#guilhem_vidal_h_lbc-au" role="her">Willelmum 
                        Vital</persName> et socium suum, hereticos, <placeName type="event_loc" ref="#vineyard_of_joan_carabula">juxta 
                            vineam den <persName ref="#joan_carabula_msp-au" role="ref">Johanni<pb n="3v"/><lb break="y" n="1"/>Carabula</persName></placeName>. 
                    Et vidit ibi <persName ref="#guilhem_de_rosengue_msp-au" role="par">Willelmum de Rezenge</persName> 
                    fratrem ipsius testis. <date type="event_date" when="1239">Et sunt<lb break="y" n="4"/>VI anni vel circa.</date></seg>
                <seg n="2" type="dep_event" subtype="belief" xml:id="MS609-0017-2" corresp="#MS609-0017-2" fn="4">Quisque dapibus nisl sed porta malesuada. 
                    Proin et velit vitae urna elementum accumsan. Nam accumsan vehicula dolor, at lobortis augue. 
                    Cras mollis scelerisque convallis.</seg>
            </ab>
        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<xsl:copy-of select="./node()"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.

Unrelated to your problem, I think instead of `<xsl:element name="{ name(.) }" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">` you just want `<xsl:copy>`. Unless you are trying to get rid of in-scope namespace, but in XSLT 2/3 the `xsl:copy` takes `copy-namespaces="no"` if you really need that.

Comment: With respect to the `<xsl:copy>` I hadn't realized that I could add an attribute inside it while copying...thus I reconstructed the element...